# Printing in web applications

Tags: javascript, html, printing, browser, right-to-left

I'm working on a web application, which works in a LAN network and I need to print some documents, which are filled in by users.
I've made the printable document via **HTML** and **CSS** but the problem is that, it is not suitable for users to force them to print a webpage by **browser print dialog**.
The idea that I came up with is to copy the printable document into the **clipboard** using JavaScript and having a **desktop application** in clients, which is running in background and **has already installed** there, to receive data and try to print the document by default printer. But there is a problem with this:

I can't make a report as same as what users see in the browser, I've tried **iTextSharp** but it has problem with **Right-To-Left** contexts.

In general the question is that how can I print a webpage without browser print dialog, considering I can install everything on clients and there is no limit for it.

Comment: Convert your output to PDF?

Comment: As I mentioned I've tried that with iTextSharp, but it has problem with RTL contexts